# How to get @keyframes opacity to change opacity every time on FireFox?

Tags: css, css-animations

My goal is to create a dropdown that fades in every time its parent element is moused over.
And, I want to use the CSS @keyframe property to control the opacity.

See the below example. It works in IE and Chrome as expected (fade-in happens on every mouse over). But, in FireFox, the fade-in happens only on the first mouse over. How can I get the fade-in to happen every time in FireFox?

CodePen showing example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEBgb

(notice the green "Baz" text fades in)

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">Foo
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="baz">
      Baz
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.foo {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333;
  color: #ededed;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bar {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  background: gray;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.foo:hover .bar {
  display: block;
}

.baz {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: green;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 2s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn 2s;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is some serious problem, just let FireFox's users use the classic interface and enable rich interface for other users.

Comment: I agree that it's not serious, but would be great to have working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you will have to adjust a few things:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ5NG/6/)**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0); /* transparent text color */
        opacity: 0; 
    }
    50% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0); /* transparent text color */
        opacity:1; 
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 1); /* fade in text color */
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.foo {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #333;
    color: #ededed;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.bar {
    display:none;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: gray;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.baz {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.foo:hover .bar {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s both; /* attach the animation to bar rather than baz */
    animation: fadeIn 2s both;
}
```

Or if you're looking to fade in and fade out you could try something like this:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ5NG/2/)**

Note that the second method uses pointer-events:none/auto so it may have compatibility issues in older browsers. Also seeing the fadeOut animation when the page first loads may be a problem.